# Return control to Selenium after executing an AutoIt script

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, focus, autoit

I am writing Selenium scripts to test my webpage. To simulate testing, a desktop application resets the date in the DB (as the actual process is run after the date changes).

Now I am able to call my application and click the button through Selenium by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\AutoIT\\DBReset.exe");`, but I am unable to return the control to Selenium after the reset is done.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform the operation by *AutoIt* using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\AutoIT\DBReset.exe");
```

Selenium still holds the focus to the web page. So once the *Windows dialog box* closes, Selenium should be able to execute the next line of code.

In case *Selenium* complains of **lost focus** you can use `JavascriptExecutor` to gain back browser focus :

- Java :

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
  ```